# Dynamic loaded libraries and shared global symbols

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries, cmake

Since I observed some strange behavior of global variables in my dynamically loaded libraries, I wrote the following test.

At first we need a statically linked library: The header `test.hpp`

```
#ifndef __BASE_HPP
#define __BASE_HPP

#include <iostream>

class test {
private:
  int value;
public:
  test(int value) : value(value) {
    std::cout << "test::test(int) : value = " << value << std::endl;
  }

  ~test() {
    std::cout << "test::~test() : value = " << value << std::endl;
  }

  int get_value() const { return value; }
  void set_value(int new_value) { value = new_value; }
};

extern test global_test;

#endif // __BASE_HPP
```

and the source `test.cpp`

```
#include "base.hpp"

test global_test = test(1);
```

Then I wrote a dynamically loaded library: `library.cpp`

```
#include "base.hpp"

extern "C" {
  test* get_global_test() { return &global_test; }
}
```

and a client program loading this library: `client.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include "base.hpp"

typedef test* get_global_test_t();

int main() {
  global_test.set_value(2); // global_test from libbase.a
  std::cout << "client:        " << global_test.get_value() << std::endl;

  void* handle = dlopen("./liblibrary.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  if (handle == NULL) {
    std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  get_global_test_t* get_global_test = NULL;
  void* func = dlsym(handle, "get_global_test");
  if (func == NULL) {
    std::cout << dlerror() << std::endl;
    return 1;
  } else get_global_test = reinterpret_cast<get_global_test_t*>(func);

  test* t = get_global_test(); // global_test from liblibrary.so
  std::cout << "liblibrary.so: " << t->get_value() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "client:        " << global_test.get_value() << std::endl;

  dlclose(handle);
  return 0;
}
```

Now I compile the statically loaded library with

```
g++ -Wall -g -c base.cpp
ar rcs libbase.a base.o
```

the dynamically loaded library

```
g++ -Wall -g -fPIC -shared library.cpp libbase.a -o liblibrary.so
```

and the client

```
g++ -Wall -g -ldl client.cpp libbase.a -o client
```

Now I observe: The client and the dynamically loaded library possess a different version of the variable `global_test`. But in my project I'm using cmake. The build script looks like this:

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT(globaltest)

ADD_LIBRARY(base STATIC base.cpp)

ADD_LIBRARY(library MODULE library.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(library base)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(client client.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(client base dl)
```

analyzing the created `makefile`s I found that cmake builds the client with

```
g++ -Wall -g -ldl -rdynamic client.cpp libbase.a -o client
```

This ends up in a slightly different but fatal behavior: The `global_test` of the client and the dynamically loaded library are the same but will be destroyed two times at the end of the program.

Am I using cmake in a wrong way? Is it possible that the client and the dynamically loaded library use the same `global_test` but without this double destruction problem?

Comment: My first reaction would be to question the need for this global variable.

Comment: Ok, in my original program this global variable is a constant provided by a statically linked library. But nevertheless it will be destructed two times in the cmake version

Comment: Same issue would apply for any singleton pattern so I don't see an issue with the global

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> g++ -Wall -g -ldl -rdynamic client.cpp libbase.a -o client
> ```

CMake adds `-rdynamic` option allowing loaded library to resolve symbols in the loading executable... So you can see that this is what you don't want. Without this option it just misses this symbol by accident.

But... You should not do any stuff like that there. Your libraries and executable should 
not share symbols unless they are really should be shared.

Always think of dynamic linking as static linking.

Answer (score 2):

If using shared libraries you must define the stuff you want to export with macro like [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility). See DLL_PUBLIC macro definition in there.

Comment: It is a general macro. I works both on GNU/Linux and Windows. See the #ifdef in declaration.

Answer (score 2):

By default, the linker won't combine a global variable (a 'D') in the base executable with one in a shared library. The base executable is special. There might be an obscure way to do this with one of those obscure control files that ld reads, but I sort of doubt it.

--export-dynamic will cause a.out 'D' symbols to be available to shared libs.

However, consider the process. Step 1: you create a DSO from a .o with a 'U' and a .a with a 'D'. So, the linker incorporates the symbol in the DSO. Step 2, you create the executable with a 'U' in one of the .o files, and 'D' in both a .a and the DSO. It will try to resolve using the left-to-right rule.

Variables, as opposed to functions, pose certain difficulties for the linker across modules in  any case. A better practice is to avoid global var references across module boundaries, and use function calls. However, that would still fail for you if you put the same function in both the base executable and a shared lib.

Comment: You mean linking the client *and* the library against `libbase.a` is a bad idea? Ok, so you suggest to not link the library against `libbase.a` because at runtime the symbols from the client are take for the calls in the library? It works... but is it legal?

Comment: I edited to simplify since I'm not entirely sure from your question which files are ending up where.

Comment: There's a commonly used statically linked library (called `libbase.a`), a dynamically loaded library (a plugin) using parts of `libbase.a` and a client loading the plugin and using parts of `libbase.a` too.

Answer (score 1):

My first question is if there is any particular reason for which you both statically and dynamically (via dlopen) link the same code?

For your problem: -rdynamic will export the symbols from your program and what probably is happening is that dynamic linker resolves all references to your global variable to the first symbol it encounters in symbol tables. Which one is that I don't know.

EDIT: given your purpose I would link your program that way:

```
g++ -Wall -g -ldl client.cpp -llibrary -L. -o client
```

You may need to fix the order.

Comment: Among some functions I defined some bulky constants in the statically linked library. The dynamically loaded library is a plugin for the client using these features provided by the statically linked library.

Comment: @phlipsy: the way you probably should use those constants is to link static library to the main executable, link the main executable with -rdynamic (as cmake does), and do not link plugins with static library. I do not know however how to link your plugin against program. You may try to factor out the common code (static library) to dynamic library and link both program and plugin against that.

Comment: Then at runtime the plugin will use the definitions of the used symbols located in the client executable? Is that legal?

Comment: Sorry, but the suggested way to link my program doesn't fit my goals. The library should be loaded dynamically as a plugin.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from doing that. But then you need to resolve all symbols from both you plugins and main program using dlsym and you just skip -llibrary from the link command.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise to use a `dlopen(... RTLD_LAZY|RTLD_GLOBAL);` to merge global symbol tables.

Comment: I had a case of SEGFAULT when catching user defined exception from loaded using dlopen library. Using RTLD_GLOBAL instead of RTLD_LOCAL solved it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would propose to compile any .a static library which you plan to link to a dinamic library, with -fvisibility=hidden parameter, so:

g++ -Wall -fvisibility=hidden -g -c base.cpp

Comment: Can you explain why?

Comment: I'm sorry, it used to be a long time when I was involved into this problem and I don't see the context anymore. However, I appreciate my suggestion was helpful. Wasn't? ;-)